# WordPress save thumbnail but don't show it

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

WordPress don't show image thumbnail but save them.

I have all version of image (eg. image.jpg, image-300x250.jpg) but WordPress don't detect them.

Anybody got same problem as here?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase, or add to the question?  I'm having trouble understanding what exactly your problem is.

Comment: WordPress don't show thumbnails. - That's problem.
I tried to upload wp-includes files again but it's didn't help.
I have thumbnails but WP can't show them. I don't know why.

Comment: How are you uploading your files?  Are you using WordPress's media library in the backend (admin)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I using media libary uploader.

Comment: And the Images show up in the media library, but with no thumbnails?

Comment: Yes. Everywhere. Admin panel and templete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3647/discussion-between-zach-l-and-goodkowski)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my thumbnail size to 300x240. It's odd but now it works!